# Persistent URL for GitHub wiki image across pushes

Tags: github

I am maintaining a page on a GitHub wiki. The page, which is in org-mode, embeds an image using the following syntax:

```
[[images/my-image.png]]
```

I wanted to update the text and the image, so I performed these steps:

- cloned that wiki from GitHub over SSH
- changed some text elsewhere in the page
- edited the image
- staged the file for the page, and the image, in git
- committed the staged files with git, and
- pushed to GitHub over SSH.

No errors were reported, and the edits to the page show up. But the page still has the old image. And if I visit the URL for the image ( https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/myuser/myrepo/images/git-flowchart.png ), I see the old image, not the new one, even if I refresh the tab in my browser.

Why isn't GitHub showing the new image, and what can I do about it? Is it at some commit-specific URL?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this was due to some kind of caching problem or other lag.

After waiting for a few minutes and refreshing the browser tab again, the new image showed up.